# TCP: connect to [AF_INET] failed: Unknown error

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to connect my computer to a OpenVPN server setup on a desktop. I am getting an error:

```
TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<IP>:<Port> failed: Unknown error
```

Where `<IP>` is the IP of the computer/WiFi and `<Port>` is the port that I setup port forwarding on to the desktop. The server seems to be working fine, but the client is not. I have no idea why this is happening, please help.

Client `ovpn` file:

```
remote <IP>
client
port <Port>
proto tcp4-client
dev tun
tls-client
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 1
remote-cert-tls server
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450

ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Client.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\Client.key"

cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
```

and here is the Server `ovpn` file:

```
proto tcp4-server
dev tun
tls-server
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ta.key" 0
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\SrverVPN.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\SrverVPN.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh2048.pem"
server 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
client-config-dir "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config"
verb 3
route-delay 5
route-method exe
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.182.0 255.255.255.0
```